# Regex match between patterns or end of line

Tags: regex

I have the following strings I am trying to match on

```
1234 foo bar
123 foo bar dr
```

Here is my pattern

```
(?!\d)(\w.*)(?=\s(court|ct|street|st|drive|dr|lane|ln|road|rd|blvd|cir|trl|trail|crossing|xing|pl|place|ave|cv|cove|trce|trace|mnr|way|loop|bnd|bend|lndg|landing|path|pkwy|parkway|pass|rdg|ridge|vw+))/i
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to match "foo bar" when it does not have a matching ending such as "dr". I've tried implementing a $ in multiple spots without any luck

Comment: are you sure that your pattern somehow corresponds to the input strings you've presented?

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use an optional lookahead:

```
(?!\d)(\w.*)
(?=\s(court|ct|street|st|drive|dr|lane|ln|road|rd|blvd|cir|trl|trail|crossing|xing|pl|place|ave|cv|cove|trce|trace|mnr|way|loop|bnd|bend|lndg|landing|path|pkwy|parkway|pass|rdg|ridge|vw+)?)
```

Here, you can always use group one, see [**a demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/GMG4pi/2) (and mind the different modifiers!).

Comment: How can i avoid matching the "dr" part. I only need "foo bar"

Comment: @JohnLang: Updated.

Comment: @Jan: I think you also can avoid *capturing* it. Use a non-capturing group in the lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

Use negative look ahead for the street types over a dot:

```
(?<=\d )((?!\s(court|ct|street|st|drive|dr|<ETC>|vw)).)*
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/FYYWxcRn8X).

The whole match (group 0) is your target input.